# MYSQL - Select one value from column or (if no value is given) select all

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin, conditional-statements

Due to lack of knowledge in MYSQL language I cannot create a query to obtain what is required.

I tried several options from stackoverflow and other places but none works.

Elaborating... I need to Select a specific value in a column BUT if that value is not given, I want to select all.

Example (pseudo code)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 'specificvalue' 
      IF 'specificvalue' IS NULL, THEN SELECT * FROM table
```

EDIT: dont want to break any rules. I added bellow an image of an example of a table.

I would like to search in FName for 'jack' in specific but if i have no name i want to search all then.

I tried to make a condition with IS NULL but I failed miserably...

I hope someone can help me again!!

[Table example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/images/proc-sql-ex3a.png)

Comment: Does the value in that selected column have to be `NULL` to select the other fields, or does the `specificvalue` (id) have to be `NULL`?

Comment: Show your table schema and some sample data, and sample output. Also, the 2nd statement ```SELECT * FROM column``` where you have column, SQL would expect a table name.

Comment: why don't you just use an `if/else` or a case?

Comment: @Philipp Maurer I need the possibility of the searched value to be none existant.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I have no knowledge in SQL... does the IF in SQL work the same as PHP for example?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/ --- https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php --- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php --- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php (ternary) - are a few links you can have a look at.

Comment: I need mysql, not php. Someone changed my tags.

Comment: With what authority is someone changing my question description for worse... stop please... or ask first.

Comment: What is the language you are using? IS your SQL coming from PHP there are options that depend on the language you use to send and receive your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `NOT EXISTS` condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = 'specificvalue'
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM table
        WHERE id = 'specificvalue'
        )
```

Comment: Excelent! Thank you Barmar. Made a simple tweak to fit my code and tested it and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is unique, ow about using IFNULL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id = IFNULL('specificvalue',id)
```

if your value is null, it looks for all rows where id=id, which is always going to be true, the id will always match itself.

IS NULL should also work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 'specificvalue' 
OR 'specificvalue' IS NULL
```